# Hostapd wpa_passphrase not working

Tags: networking, hostapd

Hi there I'm setting hostapd to create a wlan from my ubuntu computer.

I have configure some conf files following some tutorials/guides and I can detect the wlan.
The problems comes when i enter the password. Its says the password is incorrect.

here is the hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

ssid=MyNetwork
hw_mode=g
channel=1

wme_enabled=1
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CCK-40]

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

wpa=2

wpa_passphrase=YourPassPhrase

wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you entering for the passphrase?

Comment: "YourPassPhrase", case sensitive.

Comment: Take out the `**` on either side.

Comment: I meant try it without.

Comment: they were just to mark the field on the question, they are not in the file, edited anyway.

Comment: Oh. Oops. Try taking the last `e` off, just to see what happens.

Comment: Actually, the whole `Phrase` part.

Comment: Also, for the `driver` field, try `wext`.

Comment: changing the driver to `wext` doesn't work the wlan did not appear, (could no be started i guess), charged the pass to 12341234 just to be sure there is not reserved word stuff (at this point will try those kind of things). 
And thanks for your time Zacharee!

Comment: BTW I'd not use plain text `wpa_passphrase`, but `wpa_psk` (encoded with `wpa_passphrase MyNetwork YourPassPhrase`).

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked OK with these options:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

ssid=SmithFamily

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12341234

channel=1
```

But it was ignoring the password if the `wpa=2` was not specified, I got it without that part from a tutorial. It just connected without a password before adding that part.

It is also worth to check the hostapd version (`hostapd -v`) because some tools like apt-get installed an 0.x or 1.x version and latest one is 2.4, mine only worked when I compiled 2.4 with default settings.